# Sending $pdo to functions in other files through class implies an error

Tags: php, database, variables, pdo, undefined

I had a problem with sending the PDO variable to other files and use them in functions. I found out that you can place it in a class to make it avaiable, and so I found this code:

```
class DB

    {
        protected static $instance = null;

        protected function __construct() {}
        protected function __clone() {}

        public static function instance()
        {
            if (self::$instance === null)
            {
                $opt  = array(
                    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
                    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => FALSE,
                );
                $dsn = 'mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME.';charset='.DB_CHAR;
                self::$instance = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $opt);
            }
            return self::$instance;
        }

        public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
        {
            return call_user_func_array(array(self::instance(), $method), $args);
        }
    }
```

i placed it in the db.php instead of the basic connection, and used in the function that supposed to check if a user is signed:

```
include_once '../db.php';
function isUserSigned() {
    if(!isset($_COOKIE["NIK"])||!isset($_COOKIE["TOC"])) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $nik = $_COOKIE["NIK"];
        $token = $_COOKIE["TOC"];
        $stmt = DB::prepare("SELECT * FROM tokens WHERE nik=? AND token=?");
        $stmt->execute([$nik, $token]);
        $isToken = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if (count($isToken['userID'])>0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

after using the isUserSigned function, it displays following error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: pdo in
/hermes/bosnaweb07a/b263/dom.polthycom/public_html/functions/phpfunctions.php
on line 11 Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a
non-object in
 /hermes/bosnaweb07a/b263/dom.polthycom/public_html/functions/phpfunctions.php
on line 11
```

and before I decided to use classes I've also tried making the variable global, but I saw the same error as the one above. Probably I'm making some stupid mistake down here, but I really can't figure out it myself, so thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: While not the way I would build a "Singleton"  you should do `DB::instance()->prepare(...)`

Comment: Where is the rest of the code? where is this `Notice: Undefined variable: pdo in` I don't see a single use of `$pdo` in you posted code what so ever.

Comment: I'm sorry for bothering anyone because of this question, but I figured out it myself, and I would want to delete the question, as a reason of this was the stupidest one ever.

Comment: seeking knowledge is never stupid, by definition.  At the end of the day you learned something.  That's a win.